# How to pass looping data from html page to php page via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How to send looping data from html page to php page using ajax. I am trying so hard but i don't get any way passing looping data into php page.

order.html page code are described in the below:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var age = document.getElementById('age[]').value;
    var queryString = "?age=" + age ;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "example.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>



<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' id='age[]' Name='age[]' /> <br />
Name: <input type='text' id='age[]' Name='age[]'/>
<br />
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL' />
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example.php page code are described in the below:

```
<?php

$len = count($_GET['age']);

for($x=0;$x<$len;$x++)
{

echo $service[$x]=$_GET['age'][$x];

}

?>
```

Comment: I have removed the `jQuery` tag as the question is not related to jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [] should be append to the query string, not to the input name

```
var queryString = "?age[]=" + age1 + "&age[]=" + age2 + "&age[]=" + age3 ;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "example.php" + queryString, true);
```

Comment: fix grammar and add the example, hope more "comment" now :)